# Default Syntax Colour in Eclipse java

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface

Basically I changed the theme to dusk on Mint and tried to get my Eclipse to match, bad idea, everything is all difficult to see. I've got the Theme as dark, but some of the text I changed in Eclipse is still difficult to read. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling eclipse but it's not really installed, it's just extracted and I open the downloaded file. Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Open "Window -> Preferences", then "General -> Appearance", change "Color and Font Theme" to "default". Click Apply. If you can't even see the menus, you can run `eclipse -clean` to clear your settings.

Comment: I tried the clean method, it says:

"The program 'eclipse' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: sudo apt-get install eclipse-platform"

Which I did do, and it installed an older version. Is there a command I can type to install 4.4 and then I can hit -clean ?

Comment: You have to run the `-clean` with whichever version you have installed locally. On my machine, that's `/opt/eclipse/eclipse`.